# check if two lists of objects have the same value of an attribute

Tags: java

I have two lists of objects
**localList** and **remotList**, both lists have a **consent** attribute

I want to check the value of the consent attribute if the same for both lists

If Not, I want to remove all objects from localList don't have same consent value that exists in remotList and add all objects have same consent value that exist in remotList and not in localList

I implemented this solution but I want to improve it 
Java Example

```
    class Customer{

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer consent;

    public Customer(Long id, String name, Integer consent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.consent = consent;
    }

    public Integer getConsent() {
        return consent;
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    public java.lang.String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", consent=" + consent +
                '}';
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Customer> localList = new ArrayList<>();
    localList.add(new Customer(1L, "name1", 12));
    localList.add(new Customer(2L, "name2", 13));
    localList.add(new Customer(3L, "name3", 14));
    localList.add(new Customer(4L, "name4", 15));

    List<Customer> remoteList = new ArrayList<>();
    remoteList.add(new Customer(10L, "name1", 12));
    remoteList.add(new Customer(11L, "name2", 11));
    remoteList.add(new Customer(12L, "name3", 14));
    remoteList.add(new Customer(13L, "name4", 16));

    Map<Integer, Customer> map = remoteList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getConsent() , s -> s));
    Map<Integer, Customer> map2 = localList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getConsent() , s -> s));

      List<Customer> remove = new ArrayList<>();

    localList.forEach(e -> {
        if(map.get(e.getConsent()) == null ) {
            remoteList.add(e);
        }
    });

    remoteList.forEach(e -> {
        if(map2.get(e.getConsent()) == null ) {
            remove.add(e);
        }
    });

    remove.forEach(e ->  remoteList.remove(e));

    remoteList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

the remoteList

```
Customer{id=10, name='name1', consent=12}
Customer{id=11, name='name2', consent=11}
Customer{id=12, name='name3', consent=14}
Customer{id=13, name='name4', consent=16}
```

the localList

```
Customer{id=1, name='name1', consent=12}
Customer{id=2, name='name2', consent=13}
Customer{id=3, name='name3', consent=14}
Customer{id=4, name='name4', consent=15}
```

Result

```
Customer{id=10, name='name1', consent=12}
Customer{id=12, name='name3', consent=14}
Customer{id=2, name='name2', consent=13}
Customer{id=4, name='name4', consent=15}
```

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit more: "add all objects have same consent value that exist in remotList and not in localRemot" ? What is localRemot?

Comment: sorry it's localList not localRemot

Comment: "...and add all objects have same consent value that exist in remotList and not in localList"
How can they have the same consent value if they aren't even present in both lists?

Comment: My goal is to update localList  from remotList

Comment: remotList is the source

Comment: Your solution works, yes? Stack Overflow is meant to address specific programming problems. If you have functional code and are seeking assistance to improve it, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you  for your help

Comment: Can either list contain duplicate consent values?

Comment: no consent is unique

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you can create a map for the `remoteList` mapping each customer by `name`. We are doing this for being able to search the remote customers faster.

```
Map<String, Customer> customerByName = remoteList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Customer::getName, customer -> customer));

localList.removeIf(customer -> !Objects.equals(customer.getConsent(),
                customerByName.get(customer.getName()).getConsent()));
```

Please note, the `Customer` class would require a getter for the `name`.

For the second part, we can also create a map for the `localList` as we've done previously. We iterate through the `remoteList` and filter each element which does not exist in the `localList` (at least I believe this is what you would want to accomplish).

```
Map<String, Customer> localCustomerByName = localList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Customer::getName, customer -> customer));

localList.addAll(remoteList.stream()
                .filter(customer -> !localCustomerByName.containsKey(customer.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, Customer> map = remoteList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getConsent() , s -> s));
List<Customer> hasDiffLastItem = localList.stream()
                .filter(s -> !map.get(getConsent).getConsent().equals(s.getConsent()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  I used a linked list since they are more efficient at deleting items.

- first, create a comparator for a set. The tree set will take a comparator in place of an equals implementation.
- then iterate over the remote list, removing items if they appear in the local set.
- then iterate over the local list, removing items if they don't appear in the remote set.

```
Set<Customer> remoteSet = new TreeSet<>(comp);
Set<Customer> localSet = new TreeSet<>(comp);
remoteSet.addAll(remoteList);
localSet.addAll(localList);

Iterator<Customer> iter = localList.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Customer s = iter.next();
    if (remoteSet.contains(s)) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
iter = remoteList.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Customer s = iter.next();
    if (!localSet.contains(s)) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

You can combine the lists however you want but here are the results back to back.

```
localList.forEach(System.out::println);
remoteList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Customer{id=2, name='name2', consent=13}
Customer{id=4, name='name4', consent=15}
Customer{id=10, name='name1', consent=12}
Customer{id=12, name='name3', consent=14}
```

I tried different values using both your and my methods and the output was the same.  I would recommend you check it yourself as I wasn't completely certain how you wanted this to work.